# If a Lie group acts freely, then its lie algebra injects into the tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be Lie group, which acts on $M$ freely. Define the evaluation map:

$$\text{ev}_p : \ G \to M \\ g\mapsto g\cdot p$$

Is it possible to prove that the differential $$d_e \text{ev}_{p}: \mathfrak{g}\to T_pM$$ is an injection?

Comment: Prove that the group orbits are diffeomorphic to $G$ itself.

Comment: Oh thank you , Jack Lee has proved it in Proposition 7.26. The key word is the Equivariant Rank Theorem. If it's injective it's automatically immersion.